# Why am I able to pass Long to Map.get() method which is not keyed on Longs

Tags: java, generics

I've run into some funky behavior with generics and I was wondering if someone could shed some light as to why this is happening.  To start, I have a class `Foo` which has a field id.  The `hashCode` method on `Foo` just returns the id.  In another class I create a `Map<Foo, Double> bar = new HashMap<Foo, Double()`.

Then, at a later part of the code the strangeness starts, and I am able to do the following (simplified here):

```
Long baz = new Long(1);
bar.get(baz);
```

So, my question is, Why doesn't the compiler and catch this and report it as an error?

EDIT: I made one mistake in my initial question in that `get` is the method that works, not `put`.  I have posted the full code below.

```
Map<WebPage, Double> scoresForPhrase = new HashMap<WebPage, Double>();

// Now that we have a list of matching docs, we can calculate the
// Score of each word in the phrase for each document
for (String term: phrase.getWords()) {
TreeSet<Posting> wordPostings = wordMap.get(term);

    for(Long doc: matchingDocs) {
        if (docDenomScores.get(doc) == null) {
            docDenomScores.put(doc, getDocTotal(doc));
        }

        // The set is of postings, which are compared by docId, so
        // we need a temporary one to enable searching
        Posting temp = new Posting(doc, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        Posting wordPosting = wordPostings.ceiling(temp);
        WebPage page = (WebPage) mWebpageDb
                .getPageIdToWebPageTable().get(doc);

        score = getTermScore(wordPosting, page,
            wordPostings.size());
        score = score * queryTermWeights.get(term);
        Double curScore = scoresForPhrase.get(doc);
    }
}
```

As for the `Foo` class, it is:

public class WebPage implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4907557806357281837L;

private String mUrl;
private int mMaxTf;
private long mPageId;
private long mLastTimeUpdated;
private List<Long> mParentIds;
private long mContentLength;
private String mTitle;
private List<Long> mChildren;
private List<String> mAllUrls;

public WebPage(String url, long pageId, long lastTimeUpdated,
        List<Long> parentIds, long contentLength, String title, List<Long> children,
        List<String> allUrls) {
    super();
    this.mUrl = url;
    this.mPageId = pageId;
    this.mLastTimeUpdated = lastTimeUpdated;
    this.mParentIds = parentIds;
    this.mContentLength = contentLength;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mChildren = children;
    this.mAllUrls = allUrls;
    this.mMaxTf = 0;
}

public void setUrl(String mUrl) {
    this.mUrl = mUrl;
}

public void setPageId(int mPageId) {
    this.mPageId = mPageId;
}

public void setLastTimeUpdated(long mLastTimeUpdated) {
    this.mLastTimeUpdated = mLastTimeUpdated;
}

public void setParentIds(List<Long> mParentId) {
    this.mParentIds = mParentId;
}

public void setContentLength(long mContentLength) {
    this.mContentLength = mContentLength;
}

public void setChildren(List<Long> mChildren) {
    this.mChildren = mChildren;
}

public void setAllUrls(List<String> allUrls) {
    this.mAllUrls = allUrls;
}

public void setMaxTf(int newTf) {
    this.mMaxTf = newTf;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return mUrl;
}

public long getPageId() {
    return mPageId;
}

public long getLastTimeUpdated() {
    return mLastTimeUpdated;
}

public List<Long> getParentIds() {
    return mParentIds;
}

public long getContentLength() {
    return mContentLength;
}

public List<Long> getChildren() {
    return mChildren;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public List<String> getAllUrls() {
    return mAllUrls;
}

public int getMaxTf() {
    return mMaxTf;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof WebPage)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ((WebPage)o).mPageId == mPageId;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int)mPageId;
}

public String toString() {
    return mUrl;
}
}
```

Comment: At that point in the code, the declared type of `bar` must not be the same as the one you've shown.

Comment: Show your Foo class, please.

Comment: I can't believe that the code doesn't give compiler error. Are you sure you are not mixing up something?

Comment: Added relevant code above.

Comment: See my update. `get` takes `Object` not the generic type of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So two things. First, remember that due to type-erasure there is no runtime checking of generic types. The `Map<Foo, Double>` simply becomes `Map<Object, Object>`.

Second, with regards to a compiler warning or error, you should get a warning or error if `bar` is **declared** of type `Map<Foo, Double>`. But if it is **declared** as `Map`, no warning or error. My guess is that `bar` is defined as `Map bar`.

**UPDATE**

The reason there is no error on `get` is that by definition `get` takes an `Object` not the generic type. It is one of the odd things about the interface.

[Map.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: The `Map` is fully typed though, which is what makes it weird.  I've posted the relevant code above.

Comment: As stated, the get method takes Object and not K which represents the generic type for the key of the Map.  If the get method took K as the key then it would not compile.  Why the get method is like this I'm not sure.

Comment: The reason `Map`'s `get` method takes an `Object` is so that with the addition of generics for Java 1.5, the `Map` interface would still be backwards compatible with pre-generics code, when the `get` method took an `Object` as a parameter.

Comment: I don't know if that explains it since prior to Java 1.5 the `put` method took `Object` and now it takes `K,V`. The only reason I can think that they kept it `Object` was so that you could use an instance of a different type whose `equals` and `hashcode` were equivalent. Seems to me to keep this the `Map` could just be cast to a raw type.

Comment: @rgettman: It has nothing to do with backwards compatibility, and everything to do with the contract of the `get` method, which gets an element with a key that is equal, and not necessarily of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map<Foo, Double>` might have been casted to `Map`:

```
Map<Foo, Double> barOriginal = new HashMap<Foo, Double();

// ...

Map bar = barOriginal;

// ...

Long baz = new Long(1);
bar.put(baz, new Double(1));
```

Comment: FYI, the term `type erasure` has a very specific meaning and this is in regards to the run-time behavior WRT generics. Your use of the term here is misleading.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks, type erasure blurred in my head for a sec.